# How would I define a class on an interface property in typescript?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, tsd

I'm attempting to create a definition file for an API provided by a third party (Skuid) and have run into an issue representing [skuid.ui.Editor](http://help.skuidify.com/m/11720/l/205332?data-resolve-url=true&data-manual-id=11720) where Editor is a class defined somewhere else by Skuid. How would I inform the typescript compiler that `new skuid.ui.Editor()` is indeed valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally write something like this:

```
declare namespace skuid.ui {
    class Editor {
        constructor();
        // Methods and properties here
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I hadn't previously heard of the "namespace" keyword, something new to look into.

Comment: Note that `declare namepsace skuid.ui` is exactly the same as `declare module skuid.ui` -- you may see `module` used more often in older declaration files